# User Event Script 1.0 on a custom SubTab creates fields and Inline editor Sublist but does not stores data

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have created a Subtab and in that subtab a field and an inlineeditor sublist using User Event Script 1.0. Problem is the field and Inline editor Sublist are created as they are expected to be but does not stores data once I click save.
Below is the snippet for the code :

```
function beforeLoadTab(type, form)
{
  var currentContext = nlapiGetContext();
  var currentUserID = currentContext.getUser();

  if( (currentContext.getExecutionContext() == 'userinterface') && (type == 'edit' | type == 'create' | type == 'view'))
  {

    var new_tab = form.addTab('custpage_new_tab', 'New Tab');
    var field = form.addField('custpage_field', 'text', 'Field', null, 'custpage_new_tab');


   //Activity Milestones
    var list1 = form.addSubList('custpage_list1',
     'inlineeditor', 'List','custpage_new_tab');

var col1 = list1.addField('col1', 'select', 'Column 1');
    col1.addSelectOption('', '');
    col1.addSelectOption('1', 'option1');
    col1.addSelectOption('2', 'option2');
    col1.addSelectOption('3', 'option3');
    col1.addSelectOption('4', 'option4');

    var col2 = list1.addField('col2', 'select', 'Column 2');
    col2.addSelectOption('', '');
    col2.addSelectOption('1', 'option11');
    col2.addSelectOption('2', 'option12');
    col2.addSelectOption('3', 'option13');
    col2.addSelectOption('4', 'option14');

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create a script for the user interface(sublist and fields) to enter data. But you didn't create a script that would get data from the sublist and fields that you created and save it to the record you wanted to have that data.

Answer (score 2):

The fields created by your script does not have a counterpart in the backend or database, this is the reason they are not saved.  Normally script generated fields are for display purposes only.

If you want to save that information, you will either need to create a custom fields or have the script have them somewhere else like vVincenth said.